# Unable to make the program identify a non empty/ empty variable in PHP

Tags: php, html

In the following PHP code, I am trying to make `$emptyfields` become `true` if and ONLY if the variable `$name`is empty.

```
<? php
/* Gathering Data*/
$namme = $_POST['objectname'];
$species = $_POST['species'];
$power = $_POST['power'];
$properties = $_POST['properties'];

/*Writing Data to File
$filename = $DOCUMENT_ROOT.'Galaxy/data/'.'characters.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
$looper =1; */
$emptyfields = false;
if (empty($name)) {
  print '$name';
  $emptyfields= true;

}


if (!$emptyfields) {
  print '<p> Character Added! </p>
Your characer with the following details has been successfully added.  <br> <br>

Details: <br>';
  print '<table> <tr> <td> <b> Name: </b> </td> <td> '.$namme.
  '</td> </tr>';
  print '<tr> <td><b> Species: </b></td> <td>'.$species.
  '</td></tr>';
  print '<tr> <td> <b> Power: </b></td><td> '.$power.
  '</td> </tr>';
  print '<tr> <td> <b> Properties: </b></td> <td> <textarea disabled="true">'.$properties.
  '</textarea></td> </tr></table>';
} else {
  print '<p> Character Not Added! </p> 
Your characer with the following details could not be added due to empty fields.  <br> <br>';
}

?>
```

The code above has been used to do it. But somehow, even though the variable `$name` is NOT empty, the variable `$emptyfields` becomes `true`. How to prevent that?

Comment: print '$name'; should be print $name;

Comment: @Mana `$namme` != `$name` : You used `$namme = $_POST['objectname'];`

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh I did '$name' knowingly. That isn't related to the trouble I'm facing.

Comment: @Thamilan Thank you. Been trying to find out what was wrong. Silly of me to not figure the spelling mistake.

Comment: @Mana may be its not your problem but it is also a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$namme` != `$name`

You used

```
$namme = $_POST['objectname'];
```

Change it to

```
$name = $_POST['objectname'];
   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is good, you just got a typo error, just change this :

**PHP**

```
$namme = $_POST['objectname'];
```

with this

```
$name = $_POST['objectname'];
```